# call a javascript function inside a div

Tags: javascript, call

I would like to create a webpage which contains several divs each containing the same draw function with different implementation (like a generic interface). After loading the page I want to iterate through all the divs and call each draw function one after the other.

My page so far looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      // Draw all slots
      $('div.slot').each(function(i, d) {
        console.log('slot found: ' + d.id);
        // d.draw() does not work
        draw();
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="slot" id="slot1">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function draw() {
        console.log('Here we draw a circle');
      };
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="slot" id="slot2">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function draw() {
        console.log('Here we do something totally different and draw a rectangle');
      };
    </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to call the draw function of the selected div "d".
Right now it only calls the last defined draw function.

### Update:

Mind you that I can not combine the different draw methods into one which would get a parameter like shape handed in. The draw methods will be totally independent from each other.

Comment: You keep overwriting `window.draw` every time you redefine it. You either need to namespace each one (that is, attach it to an (otherwise empty) object), or to give each and every function a different name. There is no "div-scope" in Javascript ;)

Comment: Find a working solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it like

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slot" id="slot1">Draw1</div>
<div class="slot" id="slot2">Draw2</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function draw()
{
    console.log('Drawed! '+$(this).attr('id'));
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('div.slot').each(function(i, d) {
        console.log('slot found: ' + d.id);
        draw.call($(this));
    });
});
```

[**An Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UrAUe/2/).
​

Comment: Hmm unfortunately this is not what I need, each div will contain a different draw method, so passing in the id as an argument will not help. You can see it as such that I want to create a scope around the draw method for each div.

Comment: This is what it did, i didn't pass the `id` instead each `div` itself. `draw.call($(this));` is calling the method individually for each `div`.

Comment: @Fabian, check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UrAUe/2/) to understand the scope of each draw call, every `draw` call has ot's own  div scope, every `draw` uses individual `div`.

Comment: Yes but you only have a single draw method. I need one draw method per div.

Comment: Yes, it was not clear before your edit (not mentioned) but I understood what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you defining scripts in the `div`s?

Do your logic all in one script block:

```
<head>      
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      // Draw all slots
      $('div.slot').each(function(i, d) {
        console.log('slot found: ' + d.id);
        // d.draw() does not work
        draw();
      });
    });

    function draw(behavior) {
        console.log(behavior);
    }
  </script>

  <div class="slot" id="slot1" data-behavior="drew 1">
  </div>

  <div class="slot" id="slot2" data-behavior="drew 2">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you're looking to do something more complicated, you should consider building an object oriented javascript application, with each block's functionality derived from a class "slot".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Each divs draw method will come from an ajax call and will be very different from each other. Therefore I can't have just one draw method which gets passed the div.

Comment: if the draw method is coming in via ajax, can't you just use a wrapper function to call it?

Comment: AndyL: Can you give an example how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that is happening is because you keep overwriting the draw function. Why don't you have a script page where you hold an array of function pointers to the right function like so:

```
var array = (draw1, draw2, draw3, ...);

function draw1()
{
    //do your thing on div1
}

...

function drawn()
{
    //do your n thing on divn
}
```

Now for your first div you need to call draw1 which is located at index 1 of the array.

HTML:

```
<div id="draw1">

</div>
....
<div id="drawn">
```

What do ya think. Note sytax has not been tested.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I load the div contents via ajax and on every page resize I want to call the draw method of each div. I now don't want to return a draw1, ... drawn from the ajax calls, just the generic draw method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to go 'real OOP' in this case is to dispatch all on events on document level :

create a simple object and load this object in the main and the views like :

```
var events = {someCustomEventFromMain:'someCustomEventFromMain', someCustomEventFromView:'someCustomEventFromView'}
```

Now you can trigger events on document with jQuery like

```
$(document).trigger(events.someCustomEventFromMain, somedata);
```

And you can listen from any view or div or else

```
$(document).on(events.someCustomEventFromMain, function(__e, __data){
      //___e is the event emitted from __e.target
      //__data is the data object you wish to pass with the event
      //do something when event occurs

});
```

So if every subscript listens to some event at document level, in your case 'drawEvent',that should do the trick. You can even pass a parameters in the data of the event, like 'circle'.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $('#show').call(callfun());
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h:form>
  <div id="show" align="center">
    <script>
    function callfun(){
    var data = "hi";
   alert(data);
  }
  </script></div>
    </h:form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I think it may work.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You keep overwriting `window.draw()` every time you redefine it. You either need to namespace each one (that is, attach it to an (otherwise empty) object), or to give each and every function a distinct name. There is no "div-scope" in Javascript ;)

## Solution

You can name each function according to the `div`'s `id` and call it dynamically using the `object["methodName"]()` syntax to call it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      // Draw all slots
      $('div.slot').each(function(i, d) {
        console.log('slot found: ' + d.id);
        // d.draw() does not work
        window[d.id];
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="slot" id="slot1">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function slot1() {
        console.log('Here we draw a circle');
      };
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="slot" id="slot2">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function slot2() {
        console.log('Here we do something totally different and draw a rectangle');
      };
    </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> http://jsbin.com/mogeluzicu/1/edit?html,console